# How to call a traits private function outside of the trait?

Tags: php, reflection

I know, bunch of explanations on reflection on this. But I feel theres a difference with traits and classes. I just dont get this to work.

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\Sluggable;

trait HasTranslatableSlug
{
    protected function addSlug(): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class EntityController {
    function random($entity) // entity uses the trait
    {
        $a = new \ReflectionClass("\Spatie\Sluggable\HasTranslatableSlug");
        $addSlugReflection = $a->getMethod('addSlug');
        $addSlugReflection->setAccessible(true);
        $addSlugReflection->invoke(
            $a
        );
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Given object is not an instance of the class this method was declared
> in

When the controller's `random()` function is called, I am trying to call the trait's `addSlug` function on my object `$entity` which, in its own class, uses the trait. Calling `invoke` with `$entity` as first parameter also doesnt work, same error.

If I go

```
$addSlugReflection->invoke(
                $a->newInstance()
            );
```

I get: "Cannot instantiate trait Spatie\Sluggable\HasTranslatableSlug".

How do I get to the call the traits private method on my object that uses the trait?

When I write `$entity->addSlug` I get `method not defined`, probably because its private in the trait.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reflection should reflect the **provided entity** (`$entity`) and not the **trait** (`"\Spatie\Sluggable\HasTranslatableSlug"`).

```
$a = new \ReflectionClass("\Spatie\Sluggable\HasTranslatableSlug");
// changes to
$a = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
```

Second, the method was declared in **your entity instance** (`$entity`) and not in a **ReflectionClass instance** (`$a`).

```
$addSlugReflection->invoke($a);
// changes to
$addSlugReflection->invoke($entity);
```

Think of a Trait as copy-pasting code into your class (it's not exact, but it's fair).